# Android scrollbar with a extra View (screenshot included)

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview

i need some help again!

At first i really thought it was some kind of ScrollView tweak to achieve something like this:

[image]

But, as far as i know, it isnt, so, how can i achieve this kinda of custom scrollbar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/, the Rings Extended app has a implementation of it!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the handle displayed when you turn on fast scroll.

Comment: DropBox does this really strangely, but to get this kind of fast scroller you can simply call `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` on your list.

Comment: if it was the answer, and either adamp or my comments helped then please mark it as the answer so others know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [android:scrollbarThumbVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarThumbVertical) and see if that helps. I haven't used it myself so far but it seems it may be what you need.

EDIT: Also see the [API Demos -> View](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) -> Scrollbars -> 2. Fancy.

Comment: android:scrollbarThumbVertical changes the Drawable for the scrollbar itself, and android:scrollbarTrackVertical changes the 'background' behind the scrollbar :( thanks for the answer