# Custom scrollbar Android

Tags: android, scrollbar

How I can make this scrollbar:

[image]

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355984/can-we-have-a-custom-scrollbar-on-an-scrollview & Second is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485170/android-scrollbar-with-a-extra-view-screenshot-included

Comment: It didn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To change the thumb image you can simply create the following style and apply it to your ScrollView:

```
<style name="your_style_name">  
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroller_thumb</item>
</style>
```

where scroller_thumb is your custom image for the scroller thumb.

also note the following attributes:

1. "android:fadeScrollbars" which is set to false to make the thumb image stay permanently.
2. "android:scrollbarStyle" which is set to outsideOverlay to make the thumb image drawn at the "Edge of the view and overlaid" as stated here: [android:scrollbarStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarStyle)

Now, in order to put the thin line you want under the scroller, simply add an image view containing the line image, to the direct child of the ScrollView (RelativeLayout child as a direct child for the ScrollView will allow you to position the image on the right side of the view - so this is would have been my choice).

and that's it.

Comment: how to apply this style to scrollview ??

Comment: Just add a style tag in the ScrollView xml element with your custom style: style="@style/my_custom_style" (you can also do it from the layout editor)

Comment: About the line under the scroller: isn't android:scrollbarTrackVertical for that?

Comment: How would you also customize the fast-scroller bubble?

Answer (score 11):

Setting android:scrollbarThumbVertical is not the best solution, it will stretch the thumb image according to the list size...

You'd better use android:fastScrollThumbDrawable

Here's an example:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Then on the styles.xml AppTheme you add

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/scroller_style</item>
</style>
```

and on the res/drawable folder you create the file: scroller_style.xml with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scroller_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scroller"/>

</selector>
```

where scroller is your thumb image and scroller_active is your active thumb image (optional)

Comment: How can I hide scroll bar if list is empty ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, maybe setting 'android:fadeScrollbars="false"' as 'true' in ListView properties ? Can you try this ?