# Customized Vertical Scroll View

Tags: android, scrollview

I need a vertical scrollview similar as present in below image.

[image]

But I have Got scrollview as present in below picture

[image]

My code is

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar_track">
```

My problem is scroll_bar_thumb goes inside the scroll_bar_track. Give some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking here

[Custom scrollbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171755/custom-scrollbar-android)

and maybe there

https://github.com/rno/Android-ScrollBarPanel